# Determine winning percentage for MLB teams playing Sunday Night?

Tags: python, dataframe

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayqrj.png)

I am trying to determine the percentage of MLB teams that win their next game following a Sunday Night baseball game. Please see below the columns and contents of data in the rows. However, struggling to look in a efficient manner, 'Team' that played on 'Sun' and 'N', then in their very next game, bet that a Monday or Tuesday, won. I need to either count through or add the Wins and Losses to a list to count. The teams are different each week, so thinking of using the 'Game Number' to help identify the next game. But this will reset the next year.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
df['Win Percentage'] = None
df['Game 2 Win'] = None

current_year = None
current_game_number = None
current_sunday_night_teams = []

game_win_columns = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if current_year != row['Date'].year:
        current_year = row['Date'].year
        current_game_number = None
        current_sunday_night_teams = []
    
    if row['Day'] == 'Sun' and row['Day/Night'] == 'N':
        if current_game_number is None or current_sunday_night_teams != [row['Team'], row['Opponent']]:
            current_game_number = row['Game Number']
            current_sunday_night_teams = [row['Team'], row['Opponent']]
            win_percentage = None
        
        if row['Game Number'] == current_game_number:
            if row['Team'] in current_sunday_night_teams:
                team_index = current_sunday_night_teams.index(row['Team'])
                opponent_index = 1 - team_index
                
                if row['Winning Team'] == row['Team']:
                    win_percentage = 100.0
                else:
                    win_percentage = 0.0
                
                df.at[index, 'Win Percentage'] = win_percentage
                df.at[index, 'Opponent'] = current_sunday_night_teams[opponent_index]

    if row['Team'] in current_sunday_night_teams and row['Game Number'] > current_game_number:
        team_index = current_sunday_night_teams.index(row['Team'])
        game_number = row['Game Number']
        game_win_column = f"{row['Team']} Game {game_number} Win"
        game_win_columns.append(game_win_column)
        df.at[index, game_win_column] = row['Winning Team'] == 'W'

df = pd.concat([df] + [df[col] for col in game_win_columns], axis=1)

# Count all the 'True' values across all columns
true_count = df[game_win_columns].sum().sum()

# Count all 'True' and 'False' values across all columns
total_count = df[game_win_columns].count().sum()

# Calculate the overall win percentage
win_percentage = true_count / total_count

# Display the overall win percentage
win_percentage
print(win_percentage)
```

I tried running this, however, was obviously completely wrong. I believe a possible outcome is to just save the data at a team level, and count the occurrence of 'Sun' and 'N' games, followed by the 'W' that proceeds that. However, there must be a way before I repeat that 30 times.

Comment: You need to show us your data.  How is it sorted?  Is it by date?  You're only tracking one team at a time, but if you have 10 Sunday night games, you need to have a list of 10 teams where you watch for the next game.  Right?  Every Sunday night game is going to add another team to the "list-of-teams-to-watch-for-next-result".

Comment: @TimRoberts Hey Tim, I have added a image above. there is only 1 Sunday night game each week. I could be wrong, but I believe that is the best way of doing it. What are your thoughts? Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, because I don't have your data, but this will print out the percentage of games that each team won after a Sunday night win.

```
record = {}

waitfor = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if waitfor and row['Team'] == waitfor:
        if waitfor not in record:
            record[waitfor] = [0,0]
        if row['WinningTeam']:
            print{waitfor, "won after a Sunday win")
            record[waitfor][1] += 1
        else:
            print{waitfor, "lost after a Sunday win")
            record[waitfor][0] += 1
        waitfor = None
    elif row['Day'] == 'Sun' and row['Day/Night'] == 'N' and row['WinningTeam'] == 'W':
        waitFor = row['Team']

for k,v in record:
    print( "Team", k, "had a", v[1]/(v[0]+v[1]), "record after Sunday wins." )
```